# Django Rest Framework GET request with params

Tags: django, parameters, django-rest-framework, get, python-requests

I'm trying to make a get request with params (srcFilename) in Django Rest Framework. I'm pretty confused about where to add the "req.query.srcFilename" (as it would be in javascript) in django. I read I have to add the complete url with the params in "<>" as shown in the code below, but it wont find the url.

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_generate_signed_url(request, srcFilename):
    print(f'srcFilename: {srcFilename}')
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(srcFilename)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        url = blob.generate_signed_url(
            version="v4",
            # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
            expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
            # Allow GET requests using this URL.
            method="GET",
        )
        print(f"Generated GET signed URL: {url}")
        return Response(url)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import api_generate_signed_url

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path(r'signedurl?srcFilename=<srcFilename>', api_generate_signed_url),
]
```

When trying this in Postman I get the following error:

```
The current path, signedurl, didn't match any of these.
```

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHx4S.png)

Comment: Request parameters aren’t part of the path. In your `request` object they are accessed through the QueryDict `request.GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your path as below...

```
path('signedurl', api_generate_signed_url),
```

No need to write `?srcFilename=<srcFilename>`. Just remove it.

Then in your view access your request parameters through the QueryDict `request.query_params.get('srcFilename')`.

Comment: I tried that before and I get: TypeError: api_generate_signed_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'srcFilename'

Comment: removed `srcFilename` argument from your view

Comment: I'm still getting that TypeError. I added that to my view:
def api_generate_signed_url(request, srcFilename):
    print(request.query_params.get('srcFilename'))
    filename = request.query_params.get('srcFilename')
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)

Comment: Remove `srcFilename` parametere from `def api_generate_signed_url(request, srcFilename)`

Comment: Always... Happy Coding :)